# Node.js multiplayer game multi threading and multi core

Tags: node.js, multithreading, docker, multiprocessing

I'm working on an web multiplayer game. Using docker, node, digital ocean with postgres and redis for data. My docker machine has many CPUs, but node.js is only using a single CPU. Because of this I'm near the point this game can scale.

I want to be able to leverage the other CPUs. Some of the methods I've heard and read about are:

- Using child processes
- Running multiple node servers in 1 droplet
- Running multiple node servers in different droplets

I prefer not to run more node servers, if I can get away with it. The game structure is kind of like this:

Lobby (Player info, all online players etc..)
Rooms (Limited amount of players)
Games (Limited amount of players, 20-40m play time)

Lobby <=> Room => Games

I do not have a way of measuring (Open to suggestions here too), but I'm guessing most of the CPU usage are from singular games. I'm hoping for a solution somewhat like keeping Lobby & Rooms in the main thread. While all games are created in either random different threads or created in thread that has the minimum amount of active game count.

Some possible problems I foresee are messages and playerstate. A player can have multiple browser tabs open at the same time. Which means a single player object can have like 4 sessions & socket connections. 1 inside lobby, 3 inside games. Player might want to send a private message from his game to a player inside the lobby. Also when a game finishes, player state will get updated.

According to all these info, what would be my best way to proceed? Any docs, blogs, links, keywords, videos are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The typical solution for this problem is to use Redis, which it sounds like you are already doing. The idea is that you program your game server to be "stateless", meaning that all of the state is stored in Redis.

Then, you can spawn N instances of your game server, where N is equal to the number of CPUs on your VPS droplet minus 1. (Let the OS have 1 CPU for good measure.)

This is a much cleaner solution than using NodeJS Web Workers, because you don't have to worry about IPC and the lifecycle of the processes.

Furthermore, updating your game servers becomes very easy. In a server that handles state internally, your users would have to have downtime when you updated the server, meaning that they would have to end any games that they are currently playing so that you can reboot everything. But if all the state is in Redis, you can simply shutdown all your instances and start new ones with no real downtime.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **Web Workers**? They allow you to use threads in Node.js and [their API](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) is finally stable.

You can see a few examples in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@Trott/using-worker-threads-in-node-js-80494136dbb6) by Rich Trott.

**Here's a minimal example:**

```
const { Worker, isMainThread, parentPort } = require('worker_threads');
if (isMainThread) {
  // This code is executed in the main thread and not in the worker.

  // Create the worker.
  const worker = new Worker(__filename);
  // Listen for messages from the worker and print them.
  worker.on('message', (msg) => { console.log(msg); });
} else {
  // This code is executed in the worker and not in the main thread.

  // Send a message to the main thread.
  parentPort.postMessage('Hello world!');
}
```

Comment: So when I send something to a worker, I don't have to manage if it's on cpu 2 or 3 right? It's just automatically allocated? Also what if the worker has a large amount of data inside of it? Does that create a problem? Think of something like game state of a FPS map.